# Quadratic equation not adding up when I equate $x$

Tags: quadratics

I used Mathway to find x in the equation

$-1.9497137966666855 * x^2 + 0.0 * x - 1 = -0.6556211074636167 * x^2 + 0.0*x - 5$

it gave the answer $1.75811509$ and $-1.75811509$

but when I replace one of these values with $x$, for example if I plug $x = 1.75811509$ into $-1.9497137966666855 * x^2 + 0.0 * x - 1$ which is

$$-1.9497137966666855 * 1.75811509^2 + 0.0*1.75811509 - 1$$

it gives the value of $-7.02650426$ instead of $0$ (zero)

Comment: "*instead of 0 (zero)*" $\;-\;$ Why zero? The right-hand side of the original equation is not $0$.

Comment: @dxiv rhs is -0.6556211074636167 * x^(2) + 0.0*x = 5

Comment: It's $-5$ not $=5$, and if you substitute $\,x=1.75811509\,$ there, you get $\dots$

Comment: @dxiv but when I calculate -0.6556211074636167 * x^(2) + 0.0*x, x = 1.75811509 I am getting -2.02650430235 instead of 5

Comment: The RHS of the original equation is $\,-0.6556211074636167 \cdot x^2 + 0.0 \cdot x\, -5$. When $x=1.75811509$ it evaluates to $−7.0265\dots$ which matches the LHS within the precision you are working with. Keep in mind that the equation is of the form $\text{LHS} = \text{RHS}$, *not* $\text{LHS} = \text{RHS} = 0$.

Comment: @dxiv oh my bad I thought a=b=0 my bad. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have,
$$\rm{LHS}=-1.9497137966666855(1.75811509)^2-1=\color{blue}{-7.026504}2603506961$$
and
$$\rm{RHS}=-0.6556211074636167(1.75811509)^2-5=\color{blue}{-7.026504}302354686$$
which indeed verifies $\rm{LHS}=\rm{RHS}$ upto certain precision. The $\rm{LHS}$ or the $\rm{RHS}$ doesn't have to be zero necessarily.

Hope this helps. :)